# Is it possible to wrap function argument types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, parameters, arguments, wrapper, type-inference

I have a bulk of generated functions with different amount and types of arguments. Like this:

```js
function f(a: string, b: number): number;
function f1(a: number): string;
function f2(a: boolean): void;
// etc...
```

I need to wrap them like this:

```js
function myF(a: MaybeRef<string>, b: MaybeRef<number>): number;
function myF1(a: MaybeRef<number>): string;
function myF2(a: MaybeRef<boolean>): void;
// etc...
```

How can I achieve this?

I've tried something like:

```js
type MaybeRefParameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (
  ...args: infer P
) => any
  ? MaybeRef<P> // <-- It wraps all arguments, not individual
  : never

function my<F extends (...data: any) => any>(f: F): ReturnType<F> {
  return (...args: MaybeRefParameters<F>) => f(args.map(unref))
}


const myF = my(f)
const myF1 = my(f1)
const myF2 = my(f2)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Please create a fiddle with definitions and usage on which you expect to work. It will be much easier to help you then.

Comment: I made guesses about what `unref` and `MaybeRef` might look like, and also what "it does not work" might mean (that is, "It wraps all arguments").  If I made mistakes in my guesses, please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to turn the parameter tuple type of the passed in function to a new tuple type where each element is wrapped with `MaybeRef<>`.  I would suggest using the parameter tuple type `A` and the function return type `R` as separate [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters instead of using the whole function type `F` and then fiddling with [the `Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) or [`ReturnType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype):

```
function my<A extends any[], R>(f: (...a: A) => R) {
  return (...args: { [I in keyof A]: MaybeRef<A[I]> }) => f(...args.map(unref) as any)
}
```

Note that the compiler will definitely not be able to understand that `args.map(unref)` will do any kind of tuple type mapping which is different for each element.  Without *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), you can't even represent that sort of transformation in the type system directly (unless we hardcode it for `unref`).  So instead of worrying about that I'm just [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that results as [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to suppress a compiler warning.

Oh, and you had better [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax) that into `f()` as `f(...args.map(unref))` instead of `f(args.map(unref))` if you expect it to work.

---

Anyway you can verify that this behaves as desired in the type system:

```
const myF = my(f);
// const myF: (a: MaybeRef<string>, b: MaybeRef<number>) => number
const myF1 = my(f1);
// const myF1: (a: MaybeRef<number>) => string
const myF2 = my(f2)
// const myF2: (a: MaybeRef<boolean>) => void
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIAooAueAZwxi1QHMAaeAI1NWQFtGQYBKF9zmAG4AUKEiwEKdNjxIAjET4cuvcpWo0RY6HCRpMufIgBMipjhwQQUVKoBuOLMBHCA9ACoAkvFQgQweAwceAB3GCgAB0CACxA2eAgsAGsEDGisMmJhYSkDWTYATwAxMwBZKALOACUQRAAeCipaAD4GZnhyypAa+tZlGGbVPoERXJl8QqKFEg6K6tq64a5B0kaNUf1x+EnTGc75+sYLKxsV+AcnEVdXeBAMMAA6J+yACRwQ+DAbeG8oMHSQHZUukyAB+bKeADkQMCVH85BwbDu6VoCWSICywgwBQiCH23VqAAVYFAkRguGQ6gAVW4AD3JqGAZHgBCeD1gNEy8BsBW48AAvM1uagCkL+fAaSB6SBGcyCMJ4PA2RyudREFx4IThHzBcKCgr4KDZl0enVCULrvA6gBaa0-DChcIRZlQCAQbkwGjsGUYMgMVA4B3UYBYOxOZCug0sQFcYTuVzZbG440Hali+AAb1C0SgGE8ZCpININIAvlpwDpJJtDPA0HB6lTmgRaaR8abG6oqS4xjXCnUAIJ0hlMvUAbQAugwqk3EKRWU8Zv2dUKqnyMwa4BhkDB8PP2Z6uVnR95qPAUgUcIh4P3x625gT6v3j+OhSXl4RlQeHmxIgQ67U+SgF0RW4YQS2yYQwDwChtmKAVYIIRBuCuG4oNQGDJjnPZ71NNYWjaO8TQWJYBnfEjIOgh1JjkeDCkQuRkLcVDKNgqYsMI1MSMGAUhTwmgKPQqjimMWiCkQ4xQMtNCMOE9iUwfOojksaxUG43ULmAIA)